# Cannot Mount local dir to docker container

Tags: python, docker, containers, volume, mount

I have created a volume locally using:

```
docker volume create <volume_name>
```

and i can view its path using:

```
docker volume inspect <volume_name>
```

I copied a file i want to upload to the container every time it runs, using:

```
sudo scp file.txt /data/docker/volumes/store_data/_data/.
```

Now that i added manually the file into the local volume, i want to run the container mounting this local volume so that it can read the txt file in it:

Approach 1:

```
docker run --name <container_name> -v "/data/docker/volumes/store_data/_data:/app" <image_name>
```

Error this approach gives:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.txt'

Approach 2:

```
docker run --name <container_name> --mount "source=<volume_name>,target=/app" <image_name>
```

Error this approach gives:

/bin/bash: ./runit.sh: No such file or directory

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.5.5
RUN pip install docker
RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install scikit-learn
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN true
COPY ./runit.sh /app
RUN chmod 755 runit.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "./runit.sh"]
CMD []
```

runit.sh contains a !#bin/python shebang and executes a python script.

How can i mount a volume to a container? what am i missing?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just run like your conatiner like this:

```
docker run --name <container_name> <image_name>
```

you already copy everything in your Dockerfile , using `volumes` with the same destination directory `/app` will only overwrite all your data in the runtime.